# I am not sure vs I wouldn't be so sure

Tags: sentence

What is the difference between these two sentences? Do they have the same meaning? It would be better if you provide example sentences.

▪ I am not sure. 
▪ I wouldn't be so sure.

Comment: What do you mean by asking for example sentences? You've already provided two. Do you think there's a difference between the two? Why or why not?

Comment: I wanted some example sentences for my better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I am not sure" is used for something that you are not sure about in the current situation. For example, if you have a theory about something but haven't proved it yet, you would say, "I am not sure about my theory."

"I wouldn't be so sure" is used when you are talking about someone else who is already sure about their theory. This other person is already "so sure" about their theory, but if you were in their shoes, you "wouldn't be so sure."

Answer (score 0):

- If you think something isn't true, but you don't have strong evidence, you may say **"I am not sure"** to express your **doubt**.

Example : *I am not sure that he has stolen my watch.* (Expressing doubt).

- But when you want to talk about **a possibility**, you may say **"I wouldn't be so sure"**

Example : *You are telling me that he is an honest person. But I wouldn't be so sure! You don't know him.* (He is not likely to be an honest person.)

Comment: I'd say that "I am not sure" can also be used in a broader context. For example, someone might ask, "Is today Monday or Tuesday?" and you might answer, "I am not sure." You're not saying you think something is not true; you're just saying that you don't know. With "I wouldn't be so sure..." you're casting doubt on the other person's assertion.